# Color highlights have vanished in emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm using emacs on a remote Linux server that I access via ssh.

I'm editing C files that have a non-standard suffix, so I have had to manually enter c-mode with M-x c-mode every time I open one of those files.

I found this to be annoying so I started monkeying with my .emacs to make that problem go away.  This made all the color highlights in c-mode go away instead. *Correction*: **All** my color highlights are gone.

I've removed the .emacs file, logged out and logged back in, but now, the color highlights are gone.

I miss them! They were very helpful How do I get them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ha -- my own annoyance and continued searching led to this.  Add the following lines to your .emacs file:

```
(require 'font-lock)
(global-font-lock-mode t)
```